# What is the purpose of ABS pipe in an irrigation manifold

Tags: landscaping, irrigation

I need to replace a failed electric valve in my drip irrigation manifold. The pipes leading to each valve are 3/4" PVC, but they in turn are enclosed in what looks like black ABS pipe, at least 1/2" wider than the PVC. These pipes are open at the top. What is the purpose of the black pipe? Protecting the PVC somehow? I need to cut some of the black pipe away in order to get to the PVC so I can replace the valves.  Any ideas?

[image: ABS pipe from manifold]

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the black pipe is there to protect against impact damage. Were it not there the PVC could shatter relatively easy since it degrades in sunlight.

Comment: Yeah, when I finally got time to dig around there, the ABS pipe is just floating there loose.  Must be just some protection.  Thanks.